# I am having trouble coding a math function (Detailed Explanation)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, math, quantitative-finance

I am trying to code

[image: this function]

It works well when `calc_spotRate(1)` but it gives me the error when it comes to `calc_spotRate(2)`

```
import math

unit_tenor = [3, 6, 9, 12, 18]
tenor_spot = [0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00, 1.5]
ytm = [0.0346, 0.0354, 0.0359, 0.0361, 0.0369]
spot_rate = []

def calc_spotRate(i):
    sum = 0
    for x in range(0, i+1):
        if x == 0:
            SpotRate = (1/ tenor_spot[x]) * (math.log(1+tenor_spot[x] * ytm[x]))
            spot_rate.append(SpotRate)
    
        else:
            for x in range(1, i+1):
                sum += ytm[x] + math.exp(-1 * tenor_spot[0] * spot_rate[x-1])
            
            SpotRate = (1/tenor_spot[i]) * (math.log((1 + tenor_spot[0] + ytm[i]) / (1 - tenor_spot[0] * sum)))
            spot_rate.append(SpotRate)

calc_spotRate(2)
pring(spot_rate)
```

[image: error code]

IndexError: list index out of range

`calc_spotRate(2)` is supposed to give the result 0.037 (approximately)

Comment: I checked out the values of spot_rate and x right before line 17 (the error). spot_rate isn't changing size in that for loop, so spot_rate has one item, therefore spot_rate[2-1] isn't a valid index.

Comment: During the whole else part, spot_rate has one element inside it. However when i=2, in the second iteration of the loop inside else you are asking for the second element of the list. Which of course doesn't exist so you get an error. You could solve the error by changing spot_rate[x-1] to spot_rate[0] . I haven't checked the result of that so maybe it is no good for you

Comment: so..I changed the code a little bit, from `sum += ytm[x] + math.exp(-1 * tenor_spot[0] * spot_rate[x-1])` to `sum += ytm[x] + math.exp(-1 * tenor_spot[0] * spot_rate[0])`. it does not give the error, but the result give the wrong answer. Could you please tell me what's wrong with my code? I think my code and the functon above matches..

Comment: Before exp you have + instead of * maybe it's that

Answer (score 0):

Like the error say, the problem is that your calling an element in a list that doesn't exist, the index is out of range. Look at the following line:

```py
for x in range(1, i+1):
    sum += ytm[x] + math.exp(-1 * tenor_spot[0] * spot_rate[x-1])
```

and follow me. As `i=2`, `x` will be between `1...3`, not including `3`.
Now when `x=2`, you will be trying to access `spot_rate[1]` wish is not in the list. This will pass right after the `x` on the first loop will be 1, when it reach the else clause.

**NOTE:** *I think that you should name the variables on the first and the second loop defferently. Otherwise will cause you a lot of confution.*

Comment: Hi, thx for the advice. about the Note...you mean 'x' in the second for loop?

Comment: Yes exactly, at least for me, that what caused me more trouble to follow up the trace.

Comment: so..I changed the code a little bit, from `sum += ytm[x] + math.exp(-1 * tenor_spot[0] * spot_rate[x-1])` to `sum += ytm[x] + math.exp(-1 * tenor_spot[0] * spot_rate[0])`. it does not give the error, but the result give the wrong answer. Could you please tell me what's wrong with my code? I think my code and the functon above matches..